# Adding a new method to the 'train' function in caret

Tags: r, neural-network, r-caret

I would like to use caret to train a model in RSNSS (Stuttgart Neural Network Simulator).  Unfortunately, it looks like RSNSS is not yet implemented in train.  There doesn't seem to be any documentation in the train function for adding new methods, and I was wondering if anyone else had tried this on their own.

rsnss objects have both a 'train' and 'predict' method already defined, so I don't think this should be too difficult.

Thank you.

/edit: [Caret now includes](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/news.html) methods from the RSNSS package.

Comment: I suspect that Max Kuhn, the caret author & maintainer, would welcome this suggestion.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. There is already a _train_ method in RSNSS, so why can't you use it?

Comment: @Calimo: I want to use the `train` method in caret to cross-validate the model.  I can do this manually using the RSNSS train and predict functions, but it would be nice to be able to use caret to tune and validate these models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to solicit expert advice regarding pkg:caret functionality, especially for wish-list items that make sense, is to contact the author/maintainer, Max Kuhn.

Comment: I contacted Max Kuhn.  I'm also interested in learning how to implement this sort of thing myself, for future cases where I want to use a function not yet included in caret.  It looks like the latest version of caret includes the option of using a custom set of functions.

Comment: If you develop a good example feel free to post it here as an answer and take back the checkmark for your efforts.